# Is there a way to upload .feature files in Rally

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, report, rally, extentreports

Is there a way to upload .feature file to rally against any story or feature and also to publish to rally the Automated reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to link data that is incompatible. A story is a historical piece of data it is related to when it was created.

A `.feature` file is a current piece of data it documents the current state of your application.

If you try and link the two together you end up either

1. Freezing the feature files (this is very destructive)
2. Having stories with broken/inaccurate/misleading links, as the features are updated and modified to reflect the current state of the application

Both of the above are really bad things.

The thing you should link your story to is the pull request or commits that implement the story. Here you are linking data of the same type (both are historical). Note these commits will include the changes to the features that were used to implement the code, so you have an indirect connection of the type you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I do agree but it was organisational ask id we could push test cases(.feature file) and corresponding automated reports to Rally.